# Cheap underwater equipment for d300s

Tags: equipment-recommendation, underwater, cheap

I'm not rich enough to be able to buy a 2000$ case so I was considering the option of the underwater bag like this one : [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B003L75CUC/ref=pd_aw_sbs_1/177-0395843-6129018?pi=SL500_SS115&simLd=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003L75CUC)

Is this a good idea or will it kill my DSLR?

Ps: I never go under 10 meters in the water

Comment: Also see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1424/4892

Comment: @dpollitt  I've seen it but none of the answer really pleased me... That's why I'm asking it again with a more precise question

Comment: If you're not planning to do this regularly, have you considered renting?  Housings for the D300 are easy to find and rent for about US$250/week.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you want to kill your camera.  I wouldn't trust the bags, particularly the cheap ones.  Fairly reliable ones might work, but they are harder to reliably test since they rely on zippers and velcro rather than o-rings and pressure seals.  They are more designed more to protect against surface usage where the camera may get splashed or fall on the surface of the water.  They are specifically not designed for going deeper than 15 feet (about 4 meters) and even that depth is often sketchy.

The one you linked to sounds pretty reliable overall, but I'd still be a bit nervous trusting a DSLR to it for going 10 meters down as it isn't designed to go nearly that deep.  (And even if it does work right, it still is going to impact image quality significantly and be difficult to use since it isn't custom fit.)

Your better option for your use case is to get a waterproof point and shoot.